# How to fetch data from combobox to textbox using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i want to retrieve data from database to textbox when i click combobox, im already search reference to using ajax, i found some reference then i try to code but the value on textbox still not fetched data

this is my `koneksi.php` code :

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("db_test"); 
$nip = $_GET['q']; 
if($nip){ 
 $query = mysql_query("select alamat from tbl_datakaryawan where nip=$nip"); 
  while($d = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
                echo $d['alamat']; 
        }
} 
?>
```

this is my `datakaryawan.php` code :

```
<html> 
 <head> 
  <script> 
        var ajaxku; 
        function koneksi(nip){ 
             ajaxku = buatajax();
             var url="koneksi.php"; 
             url=url+"?q="+nip; 
             url=url+"&sid="+Math.random(); 
             ajaxku.onreadystatechange=stateChanged; 
             ajaxku.open("GET",url,true); 
             ajaxku.send(null); 
        } 

        function buatajax(){ 
             if (window.XMLHttpRequest){  
              return new XMLHttpRequest(); 
             } 
             if (window.ActiveXObject){  
              return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
             } 
             return null; 
        } 

        function stateChanged(){ 
            var data; 
             if (ajaxku.readyState==4){ 
              data=ajaxku.responseText; 
              if(data.length>0){ 
               document.getElementById("alamat").value= data 
              }else{ 
               document.getElementById("alamat").value= ""; 
              } 
             } 
        } 
  </script> 
 </head> 
<body>
    Nama :
    <select size="1" name="karyawan" id="karyawan" 
    onchange=ambildata(this.value)> 
    <option selected>--Pilih Karyawan--</option> 
    <option value="889456">Desrizal</option> 
    <option value="889457">Nurmi Yulita</option> 
    <option value="896543">Budi Hartono</option> 
    </select> 

    </p> 
    <p> 
        Alamat : <textarea rows="4" id="alamat" name="alamat" 
        cols="42"></textarea> 
    </p> 
        Pada contoh berikut anda akan memilih nama dan mengambil data alamat di 
        database<br> 
        berdasarkan nama tersebut dan menampilkannya di halaman ini tanpa harus 
        me-reload<br> 
        keseluruhan halaman 
</body> 
</html>
```

[with this code will produce output like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiApa.png)

i want, when i click combo box with value budi hartono, then on textarea wil fetched data 'alamat' .

Comment: You need to learn how to break your requirement to small tasks and mature sure each task works by itself. Otherwise you'll never know how things work and why they fail.

Comment: im stack because this code dont have error, but still not fetched data from combobox,